# How to find the average of cells in a column when my serial number is odd or even in Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Iam trying to find the average of by data in Column B when my serial number in Column A is an even number in excel 2007. iam trying to use the formula =AVERAGEIF(A7:A1500,MOD(A7,2)=0,B7:B1500) but an error is  shown as "#DIV/0!". I think there is a problem in specifying MOD function. Can some one help please.

Comment: That's not what `AVERAGEIF` function is for. See this [http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/averageif-function-HA010047433.aspx](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/averageif-function-HA010047433.aspx).

Comment: So how i can specify the condition ? Can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following formulas:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((EVEN(A7:A1500)=A7:A1500)*1,B7:B1500)/SUMPRODUCT((EVEN(A7:A1500)=A7:A1500)*1)
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(A7:A1500,2)=0)*1,B7:B1500)/SUMPRODUCT((MOD(A7:A1500,2)=0)*1)
```

Comment: No it is not working. i just want the average of B1,B3,B5... where A1,A3,A5...contains odd values. Similarly average of B2,B4,B6... where A2,A4,A6... cells contain even values. OR more simply the other way of thinking the logic is i want to find the average of alternate cells where i can specify the starting and ending cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try `=IF(MOD(A7,2)=0,AVERAGE(B7:B1500),0)`

Comment: If the condition is satisfied i.e., "A7" cell contains an even number it is just calculating the average of B7:B1500. But what i want to do is take the average of all the cells of column B for which the corresponding column A is even only.